# Python-PostgreSQL: How to connect database via network IP

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

For my Django project I am using 'postgresql_psycopg2' and my DB is residing at a common server on the network. How can I connect to that DB using the IP address as 'host' like we do in MySQL? I have tried but it always shows the following error:

> OperationalError at /
>       could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Can you connect to your DB via psql command in terminal with parameters from your settings.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not related to Django, you just need to simply put the database server's ip in `DATABASES['default']['host']`, as you did.

The problem is postgresql denies remote access by default. You have to first edit the `pg_hba.conf` file on your database server and put a line like this in it:

```
host    db_name    user_name   192.168.1.1/32    md5
```

where you put your target database and user (same as those you enter in django settings) and specify the ip range of the allowed hosts to connect to that database via that user. Then you restart postgresql and now you can remotely connect to the your database. Also check if there isn't any firewall blocking you to access that port on the database server.

For more detailed instructions, see [[1]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) or [[2]](http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/postgres/remote-access).